# Passing variable values into javascript from html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to get this to work and I've tried quite a bit.  I have a jscript file that contains a very long and involved function that does various calculations.  I am trying to pass values for variables that exist within the jscript file.  The jscript file contains 3 variables that I would like to have the ability to change from the HTML forms page.

The variables within the jscript file that I am trying to change are vehicleWeight, wheelbase, and tireChoice.  Note that the jscript file works flawlessly but I'd like to be able to change the variables without going in and manually saying var vehicleWeight = 300, etc.  The function I am running in framework.js is Main.

This is what my HTML page looks like.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="framework.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowCalculation() {
            Main($("#wheelBaseTxt").val(), $("#tireChoiceSel").val(), $("#wheelBaseTxt").val());
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Vehicle Weight:
    <input id="vehicleWeightTxt" type="text" /><br />
    Tire Choice:
    <select id="tireChoiceSel">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select><br />
    Wheel Base: <input type="text" id="wheelBaseTxt" /><br />
    <input type="submit" onclick="ShowCalculation(); return false;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post the code for `Main` and any other code required to support it.

Comment: That all looks splendid. What's your Javascript look like?

Comment: Without knowing `Main`, it isn't possible to diagnose.

Comment: Are you wanting to pass the $("#wheelBaseTxt").val() twice? <=Main($("#wheelBaseTxt").val(), $("#tireChoiceSel").val(), $("#wheelBaseTxt").val()); =>

Comment: RobB! I just caught that too, Thanks.  I changed it to vehicleWeightTxt and it seems to be passing correctly.  Now I think it is passing everything in correctly, I just need to pass it back to the HTML page(I want to pass back a few variables).  

Guess I should do this with an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to say without viewing your javascript include but you may need something similar to the code below inside your `Main` function.

```
var vehicleWeight = 0.0;
var wheelbase = 0.0;
var tireChoice = 0.0;
function Main(inpVehicleWeight, inpWheelbase, inpTireChoice) {
   vehicleWeight = inpVehicleWeight;
   wheelbase = inpWheelBase;
   tireChoice = inpTireChoice;

   // ... other calculations, etc ...

}
```

Comment: I am doing exactly this in my jscript file.  I would attach the jscript file but its over 3,000 lines of code.  Thanks though

Comment: That sounds like some pretty complex javascript code, perhaps you are running into an exception?  Do you have try / catch blocks in your javascript code to trap errors?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the variables defined in the framework js are global there is no way you can change their values.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowCalculation() {
            alert($("#wheelBaseTxt").val()  + "; " +  $("#tireChoiceSel").val()  + "; " +  $("#wheelBaseTxt").val());
        }
</script>
```

...and it does not seem to be a problem with jQuery... the values are there.
Use this approach to test. The problem may be within the Main() function.